# Plotting a line tangent to a Function

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to get a line to appear on this function, but it doesn't seem to appear even after attempting to plot it. I have two production possibility frontiers and would like to provide a tangency line for both functions.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as py
x = np.linspace(0.1,10, 400)
x2 = np.linspace(0.1, np.sqrt(199.99),800)
def ppf(x,Ax):
    return np.sqrt(100-(x**2/Ax))
Ax=1
x = np.linspace(0.1,100, 1000)
a=b=1

def indiff(x,ubar):
    return ubar-x
plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
plt.plot(x, ppf(x,1))
plt.plot(x,indiff(x,100))
plt.plot(x2,ppf(x2,2))
plt.xlabel("Coconuts",fontsize="20")
plt.ylabel("Fish", fontsize="20")
plt.xlim(0,15)
plt.ylim(0,np.sqrt(198))
plt.margins(y=.1, x=.1)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.gcf()
plt.tick_params(labelsize="20")
plt.show()
```

Is there an error in my code that's preventing the line from appearing or perhaps is it where it is on the code block?

Comment: I figured it out. If anyone has a similar problem, feel free to leave a message here.

Comment: Are you planning on manually changing the value of `ubar` until it looks to be tangent?

Comment: @Baquino you can just answer your own question here, which will then be helpful for someone else one day.